# VBA/ACCESS EASY: Query for yes/no field in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Looking for a query syntax for vba code that allows to find if a yes/no field = no.

```
 Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from tblStepCalendar" & _
                                            "Where (groupNr like '*" & txtGroupNum.Value & "*' )" & _
                                            "AND (CanceledContact = 0)", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SQL statement is accurate, the following should work.

```
Dim strSQL AS String
Dim db AS DAO.Database
Dim rsStepCalendar AS DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT" & VbCrLf & _
         "    S.*" & VbCrLf & _
         "FROM tblStepCalendar S" & VbCrLf & _
         "WHERE S.groupNr LIKE '*" &  txtGroupNum.Value & "*'" & VbCrLf & _
         "AND S.CanceledContact = 0"

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rsStepCalendar = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
```